# Is quantum spin intrinsic, or a function of some other characteristic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-spin, quantum-interpretations, chirality

In my current understanding, I have been told that the spin of quantum particles is simply intrinsic to them. That, particles are simply right-handed or left-handed... just because they are. To me, that seems then that we should then treat handedness like it is just as distinguishing of a property as mass, or charge, or color charge. Almost like the standard model should be doubled, or mirrored. Like, right-handed, blue, up quarks should be considered as a wholly different particle from a left-handed blue up quark.

But wouldn't something HAVE to catalyze the spin? Like a ball rolling down a hill hits a rock, and how it first strikes that rock determines whether it continues its rolling spinning to the right or to the left. Could spin be acquired, for instance, during the big bang, by the first interaction of a particle as it "hits" the higgs field? And some characteristic of the particle to that point determines which way it "glances" off of the higgs field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard Model actually is doubled in the way you imagine, up to a point. Without the Higgs, it would be correct to treat right-handed up quarks and left-handed up quarks as completely unrelated particles. This is easiest to see for neutrinos, which have only one handedness. The Higgs couples left and right-handed particles together, as part of how it gives them mass. That means that if you see a left-handed quark, and you observe it later, it might be right-handed instead, due to interaction with the Higgs field.

In part because of this, nothing needs to "catalyze" or otherwise start particles spinning. (And more generally, these kinds of properties don't really need to have a beginning to them, any more than something needs to start photons moving...there isn't a preferred state of rest, that's Artistotelian physics.)